# How to setup VNC server for 1920 x 818

Tags: windows-10, vnc, vncserver

I have a win10 pc running UltraVNC server. If that PC is set to standard resolution (1920 x 1080) then VNC clients connect and display perfectly.

But ...

I created a custom resolution in my NVidia GT520 card in the server for my 2.4:1 home theater projection screen of 1920 x 818.

And when I connect from any VNC client, the screen is perfect for 1 second, but then it gets deinterlaced (I see three separate copies of every other horizontal line).

Is there some way to setup the Ultra VNC server to handle this resolution?

Comment: @ITSolutions  Thanks but was looking for VNC solution not proprietary.

Comment: First, VNC is not proprietary....it's open source.  Second, correct me if I am wrong..I thought you had to connect to other machines through TeamViewer servers, as opposed to direct connect (VNC), hence how people got hacked by Chinese via TeamViewer.

Comment: Okay, fair enough on the part that VNC is open source, I assumed you were running compiled code for your needs and not compiling it or looking over the logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I changed resolution to 1920 x 804 and removed some video software and codecs.

Problem went away and now I have VNC working perfectly. I can't say whether it was the resolution change or software removal, unfortunately.